# Curve fitting: Scaling the sigmas so that the reduced chi-squared statistic = 1. Is this a good heuristic?

Tags: python, chi-squared-test, standard-error, estimators, curve-fitting

In the official documentation for the python function **scipy.optimize.curve_fit**, the following description is given for a boolean-typed parameter **absolute_sigma**.

> If False (default), only the relative magnitudes of the sigma values matter. The returned parameter covariance matrix pcov is based on scaling sigma by a constant factor. This constant is set by demanding that the *reduced chisq* for the optimal parameters popt when using the scaled sigma equals unity.

Here, "reduced chisq" is defined as "chisq/(M-N)" where M is the number of data points and N is the number of curve fit parameters.

That is, the default behavior of the curve_fit function is to scale the initial estimates of the sigma values so that the resulting reduced chi-squared statistics equals 1. According to the documentation, the curve_fit function uses these scaled values to compute the covariance matrix (the *pcov* output) of the resulting curve fit parameters, as written in the above-cited documentation.

**1.** Is this a good heuristic? (i.e., is there a theoretical justification? Could anyone give me a **precise mathematical theorem?**)

**2.** If such a theoretical justification exists, does it work only for linear models? Or, does it work **even for non-linear models?**